# Не запускается Redis-server внутри докера

Tags: python, docker, redis, aiogram-3.x

Ситуация: хочу сделать контейнер из бота и бд redis для хранения данных. Для этого как я понимаю нужно в докерфайле прописать все команды для установки redis-server
Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN sudo apt-add-repository ppa:redislabs/redis \
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade \
RUN sudo apt-get install redis-server \
RUN sudo service-redis-server restart
RUN pip install -r app/requirements.txt && pip install redis && sudo apt-get upgrade
EXPOSE 6379
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR app
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

Когда пытаюсь создать изображение выдаёт ошибку:

```
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                             0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                          0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 436B                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9                                                                                                                                                 1.0s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9@sha256:98f018a1afd67f2e17a4abd5bfe09b998734ba7c1ee54780e7ed216f8b8095c3                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                             3.4s
 => => transferring context: 398.59kB                                                                                                                                                                         3.3s
 => CACHED [2/6] COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [3/6] RUN sudo apt-add-repository ppa:redislabs/redis RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade RUN sudo apt-get install redis-server RUN sudo service-redis-server restart                   0.7s
------
 > [3/6] RUN sudo apt-add-repository ppa:redislabs/redis RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade RUN sudo apt-get install redis-server RUN sudo service-redis-server restart:
#0 0.612 /bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found
------
Dockerfile:3
--------------------
   2 |     COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
   3 | >>> RUN sudo apt-add-repository ppa:redislabs/redis \
   4 | >>> RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade \
   5 | >>> RUN sudo apt-get install redis-server \
   6 | >>> RUN sudo service-redis-server restart
   7 |     RUN pip install -r app/requirements.txt && pip install redis && sudo apt-get upgrade
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c sudo apt-add-repository ppa:redislabs/redis RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade RUN sudo apt-get install redis-server RUN sudo service-redis-server restart" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так

Comment: уберите либо лишние `RUN` (строки 4-6), либо лишние обратные слэши (строки 3-5).

Comment: Ну и ещё стоит обратить внимание на ошибку `sudo: not found` — зачем тут sudo вообще? Если я правильно помню, команды RUN и так по умолчанию выполняются от имени root